# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when opening Notebook in JUPYTERLAB Azure ML Studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

So our team created a new Azure **Machine Learning** resource, but whenever I try to add a new notebook and try to edit it using "JUPYTERLAB" i get `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error, but the same notebook, when edited using `EDIT IN JUPYTER` works perfectly.

This is a blank and clean notebook, I also tried 2 different laptops and multiple browsers per laptop, same error. I also tried incognito and clearing cookies, but to no avail.

[image]

update: I seem to have accidentally replicated the issue and I now know what is causing it, the situation is that Im using my work laptop and constantly switching VPN connections, and some times, connecting to the AZURE PORTAl OUTSIDE the VPN. So, when you've worked on a notebook while inside a VPN, then you disconnected, and tried loading the notebook sometime later, you will encounter this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has stomped me for hours, but I was finally able to fix it. What I did was I opened a terminal and did a Jupyter lab rebuild "jupyter lab build"

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe add a little more info about how you opened a terminal into the VM. through the portal? through jupyter notebooks?

Comment: ok, i added another screenshot above on how i opened the terminal to connect to the Azure Compute

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance? Sometimes the VM has a fatal issue and a new one needs to be spun up.

Also try modifying the working Jupyter Notebook url by adding `/lab` to the end.

Comment: Yes, i actually created a new one.

Anyway, this problem has stomped me for hours, but I was finally able to fix it. What I opened a terminal and did a Jupyter lab rebuild

"jupyter lab build"

Comment: you opened a terminal inside the VM and rebuilt jupyter lab?

Comment: yes, ive been using Azure ML for a few months now, and this is the 1st time I encountered this issue

Comment: Way to get the problem solved! Can you please create an issue here with the steps to reproduce the error? This will help the team get started on fixing this bug
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks

Comment: Ok then, will do. Thank you